# CsvHelper in C#: writing a list of strings as one record

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper in C#. I have a list of strings and I want this list to be one record in the csv file, with each element in the list being one field.
I am calling csv.WriteRecord(listOfStrings) but getting the error:

> Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records? | Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records?

Each list should be one record in the file, one line.
How do I achieve this?
I know I can use WriteField for each individual field but am trying to speed up the program by limiting how many method calls are invoked, so attempting to have just one WriteRecord call for the whole row.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Limiting method calls isn't necessarily the key to getting better performance.  Not all method calls are created equally.

Comment: CSV is a string so to combine an array into one CSV string use : string.Join(",", myArray);

Comment: @jdweng What if the string contains a `"`, `,`, or `\r\n`? This is how bad CSV files get written. You need to follow [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)